# How to convert all PNG image in folder to JPG without interpolation

Tags: python, imagemagick

I have some mask files in my folder stored in PNG format.
I want to convert all PNG images to JPG **without** interpolation.
An example PNG image can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WODsOzIlgbgapDY3GUwE9EhxQlrszmCR/view?usp=sharing).
I tried the following command of the ImageMagick but it didn't work.
Input image size is 640x512 (w,h).

```
convert -interpolate Integer -filter point '*.png[640x]' -set filename:base "%[basename]" "%[filename:base].jpg"
```

Thanks.

Comment: Saving categorical data (classes and masks) as JPG is nearly always a bad idea because it blurs and diffuses edges introducing new categories/classes. Are you sure you want to do that? Why?

Comment: Also there's no real *"interpolation"* when doing a straight format conversion - it happens with operations like resizing and distorting.

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks for your comment. The method only accept an image with jpg file format. It was the reason to want to convert png images. As you stated above, if there no escape from an interpolation, I would like to close the question or if you share your comment below as an answer of question I can accept it as a solution.